# Get method name of property setter in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mocking, fakeiteasy

I am using FakeItEasy to check that a call to the public setter method of a property has been called.

The property is called `Description`, and at the moment I am testing it like this:

```
A.CallTo(model)
    .Where(x => x.Method.Name.Equals("set_Description"))
    .WithAnyArguments()
    .MustHaveHappened();
```

This works functionally, however the downside of using a magic string for the method name is that if I refactor the name of the property, the test will fail and I will have to manually change the strings in all of the tests.

Ideally, I would like to know of a way to do it like in this piece of pseudocode:

```
var setterName = model.GetType()
                         .SelectProperty(x => x.Description)
                         .GetSetterName();

A.CallTo(model)
    .Where(x => x.Method.Name.Equals(setterName))
    .WithAnyArguments()
    .MustHaveHappened();
```

This way, if I right-click refactor the `Description` property, the tests won't need to be updated. How can I do this?

Comment: As an aside, you can omit `WithAnyArguments` here, if you're so inclined.

Comment: Why is that @BlairConrad? Is `WithAnyArguments` implied if I don't specifically declare the constraints?

Comment: that's exactly why. Hmm. I can't put @JamesMonger in here. At the beginning, it seems. Ah. Because "the post owner will always be notified". The things you learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this with the `nameof` keyword: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx

So I guess it would be something like

```
.Where(x => x.Method.Name.Equals("set_" + nameof(x.Description))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pseudocode was on the right track.

```
var setterName = model.GetType()
                     .GetProperty(nameof(Description))
                     .GetSetMethod();
```

Note that `nameof` is only available in C# 6.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Dennis_E. I chose Terje's answer as it is a bit more concise, however I appreciate you taking the time to answer. I also appreciate that yours is a bit more robust as it does not even include the `set_` string. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Note that as of FakeItEasy 2.0.0, if the setter has a getter as well, you can use the new [A.CallToSet method](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-a-property-setter):

```
A.CallToSet(() => model.Description).MustHaveHappened();
```